# Best practice to download blobs from Azure container

Tags: python, azure

I have an Azure container with thousands of blobs that each of them saves in a directory `id/year/month/day/hour_minute_second/file.json`. I want to download all `file.json` for an `id` between `start_date` and `end_date` in python. For this purpose, I use the `BlobServiceClient` from the `azure` python package. Before downloading each JSON file, I will check the blob directory existence using the `get_blob_client(blob=blob_dir).exists()` method.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd


class AzureContainerClient(object):
    def __init__(self, account_url="https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/",
                 container_name='json',
                 credential="azure"):

        self.account_url = account_url
        self.container_name = container_name
        self.credential = credential

        # Connect to the Azure
        self.__connect()

    def __connect(self):
        """
        Connect to Azure container_name.
        :return:
        """

        self.blob_client_server = BlobServiceClient(account_url=self.account_url, credential=self.credential)
        self.container_client = self.blob_client_server.get_container_client(container=self.container_name)

    def close(self) -> None:
        """
        Close the connection.
        :return: None
        """

        self.blob_client_server.close()

    def is_exist(self, blob: str) -> bool:
        """
        Return True if blob exist in self.container_name else False
        :param blob: blob address
        :return:
        """

        return self.container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob).exists()

    def read_blob(self, blob) -> dict:
        """
        Read the blob from container_client.
        :param blob: blob directory
        :return:
        """

        data = self.container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob).download_blob().readall()

        # Load the binary data into json
        # data = json.loads(data)

        return data

def get_files(ids: list, start_date: str, end_date: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Get the json files for  ids from start_date to end_date.
    :param ids:
    :param start_date:
    :param end_date:
    :return:
    """

    date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='H')

    # Get the generator directories for each id between start_date and end_date
    stores_dates_gen = product(ids, date_range)

    azure_container_client = AzureContainerClient()

    data_list = []
    for id_date in stores_dates_gen:
        # Get the blob directory
        id_date_blob = f'{id_date[0]}/{"/".join(id_date[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S").split("-"))}/file.json'

        # Check the existence of the id_date blob in container
        if not azure_container_client.is_exist(id_date_blob):
            continue

        data = azure_container_client.read_blob(blob=id_date_blob)

        data_list.append((id_date[0], id_date[1], data))

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_list, columns=['id', 'dateTime', 'data'])

    return df
```

However, it takes too much time. It is mostly because of checking the existence blob (`azure_container_client.is_exist(id_date_blob)`). What is the faster solution to downloading all existing blobs?

Comment: Can you give an example of a blob URL/name that you want to download?

Comment: `1/2023/01/15/22_00_00/file.json` @GauravMantri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the existence of each blob, what you could do is try to read the blob directly. Basically you would get rid of the following lines of code:

```
        if not azure_container_client.is_exist(id_date_blob):
            continue
```

If the blob does not exist, the read operation will throw an error.

What you would need to do is catch this error and check the status code of the error. If the status code is 404, that would mean the blob you are trying to read does not exist and you move on to the next blob in your list.

This would reduce the time considerably as you have reduced the number of network operations by half.

Comment: Is there any option to download batch blobs?

Comment: No. What you can do is download the blobs in parallel (though I’m not sure how you would do it in Python).